# get value using php to javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have on my page php and javascript code but what I want to do here there is a value on php I want to grab it to my javascript code

I will specify it here

here's my javascript

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "@id": "http://domain.com",
                "name": "Home"
            }
        }, {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
                "@id": "http://domain.com/foldera",
                "name": "foldera"
            }
        }, {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 3,
            "item": {
                "@id": "http://domain.com/foldera/folderb",
                "name": "folderb"
            }
        }, {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 4,
            "item": {
                "@id": "http://domain.com/foldera/folderb/file.php",
                "name": "GRAB IT HERE"
            }
        }]
    }
</script>
```

there on position 4 on my js code i have market to grab it there `"name": "GRAB IT HERE"`

here is my php code

```
<?php
    $file = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));

    $Pages = array(
        'foldera' => 'foldera',
        'folderb' => 'folderb',
        $filename => 'WHATEVER IS IN HERE'
    );

    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

there i mrked on my php code `$filename => 'WHATEVER IS IN HERE'`

the poin is to get that value from php inside where it says "GRAB IT HERE"

hope you get it. sorry for a long question

Comment: How are these JavaScript and PHP codes related?  Can't you just `echo` the PHP value like you would anywhere else?

Comment: not sure dear but i want some to get value from php to js

Comment: from `WHATEVER IS IN HERE` to `GRAB IT HERE`

Comment: If you're "not sure" how any of this code is even being executed, then what do you expect to accomplish here?  First you need to at least determine how you're *running* this code, before you can modify it to do something else.

Comment: what i mean i am not sure how can i do it. i don't think it's big deal it's only getting value from here to there @David

Comment: So then do: `echo $Pages[$filename];` where you want to print the value.  That's how you would output what's in that variable.

Comment: @David i get empty when i checked source code like this `"name": ""`

Comment: Then that value isn't defined where you're trying to echo it.  A value has to exist before you can print it.  As much as you didn't want to, you're going to have to actually try to think about what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

When you load your Javascript, If it's in a HTML compatible with PHP ( ends with .php )  you can simply echo your value in a string.

Html

```
<body>
    <!-- ... --> 
    <script>
        /*...*/
        var value = "<?php echo $variable; ?>";
        /*...*/
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

If it's not, what you can do it declare a global variable with in your HTML, assign the value you need and retrieve this variable in your javascript. :

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>var myvalue = "<?php echo $value; ?>";</script>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the in your Javascript :

```
var value = myvalue;
```

I don't recommand the last option since it allows the clients to modify the variable.

Comment: dear thanks for your answer but like i said i only want to get value from `WHATEVER IS IN HERE` to `GRAB IT HERE`

Comment: well you can simply do `"item": "<?php echo $filename ?>".`

Comment: i did like this `"@id": "http://domain.com.com/foldera/folderb/file.php",
     "name": "<?php echo $filename ?>"` i get empty when i checked source code like this `"name": ""`

Comment: Have you checked if your variable `$filename` is not empty ?

Comment: if you mean here on my php `$filename => 'HERE'` it's not empty but i think it's not as "variable" is it ?

Comment: can you dear check my whole php code above ? i don't have `$filename` anywhere else on my page

Comment: Yea i just got that, Actually you need to call `$Pages[$filename]` sorry my bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135984/discussion-between-nicolas-and-mm-pp).

Comment: bro check my question at this link if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430239/heres-my-javascript-to-resize-iframe-and-need-some-edit