# here's my javascript to resize iframe and need some edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Here's my iframe it's inside a div with button

```js
   function myFunction() {
     var url =document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src");
     var newUrl = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("width")) + "width=320&height=270";
     document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src",newUrl);
     document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("style","border:none;overflow:hidden;width:320px;height:270px;");
      }
```

```html
  <div style="width:auto;height:auto;" id="mydiv">
    
       <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://domain.com/page.php?width=400&height=400" height="400" width="400"></iframe>
    
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Size</button>
```

What I need here is my code works it will change the size of iframe and its src link is size. But as you see, my div with id of "mydiv" has style width and height is auto. What I need my code also to be 100% full width on width and height when I make window larger that div is size increase but iframe doesn't change because it has fixed size.

I have tried

```
("style","border:none;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;")

("width")) + "width=100%&height=100%"
```

but it doesn't work correctly. Either iframe is messed up, but doesn't work right. Hope you understand I really need help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** EDIT **

It turns out I did completely misunderstand the question. You wish the content of the IFrame to fill the IFrame? I don't think you can do what you want.

If you need to resize the content inside an IFrame:

- Edit the CSS of the page inside the IFrame.
- If the IFrame content has the same domain name as your parent, then you can access its DOM using javascript, and manipulate.

Neither of these work for your code example though.

I've played around with some CSS3 in the snippet which makes the content look larger. Maybe something like this could help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
            
            #div {
              width: 600px; 
              height: 600px; 
              padding: 0; 
              
            }
            
            #iframe {
              width: 480px; 
              height: 480px; 
              border: 1px solid black;
              
              transform: scale(1.25);
              transform-origin: 0 0;
              
              /* browser compatibility */
              -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
              -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;   
              -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
              -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
              -o-transform: scale(1.25);
              -o-transform-origin: 0 0;  
              -ms-zoom: 1.25;         
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
            <iframe id="iframe" src="http://domain.com/page.php"></iframe><br />
        </div>       
        
        <!-- uncomment to view the original size of the content inside the iframe -->
        <!--
        <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://domain.com/page.php?width=400&height=400" height="600" width="600"></iframe>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: dear your code worked but src link is not full width and height with the div. it's on fixed size of width=320&height=270

Comment: if i make it `page.php?width=100%&height=100%` it doesn't work

Comment: updating the iframe url to: page.php?width=100%&height=100% wont do anything to the iframe, it only changes whats rendered inside the iframe.

set the style on the iframe to:
style="none;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;"

Comment: but bro i have to make the content of iframe 100% width and height i don't understand what you mean by rendered

Comment: I think I totally misunderstood your question.. I've changed my answer

Comment: dear. you have still misunderstood on my question. i give you an example. using youtube iframe becomes like this `<iframe width="400" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r3BdnFMpAQM?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` you see this is the link of iframe or src `https://www.youtube.com/embed/r3BdnFMpAQM?ecver=1` we don't need to make it like this `https://www.youtube.com/embed/r3BdnFMpAQM?ecver=1&width=400&height=400` because only giving size to iframe it will make the video full size as iframe. but some other players doesn't. that is why i want to make the link 100%

Comment: i want to make the link 100% in width and height but if i make it `width=100%&‌​height=100%` only this thing doesn't work `100%` i don't know what other options i have to make it full width and height. if i put `100%` it will make it larger than iframe is size

Comment: Adding the width & height to the URL parameter is functionality specific to youtube. They have code their side that uses those URL parameters to do stuff to the size of the video.

Comment: which link specifically are you trying to get to be 100%?

Comment: bro. those are private links . but my point is. on css we can make width and size `auto` or `100%` but on links like this `page.php?width=400&height=400` how can make that width and height to 100% or to auto instead of 400

Comment: Tried my best to understand, Im still not sure I do.  The url parameters "page.php?width=400&height=400" have nothing to do with styling. 


They are just parameters that can be read by code written on page.php.


If you want page.php to resize using those parameters. Then you need to add some code to page.php like:


<body style="width:<?php echo $_GET['width']; ?>;height:<?php echo $_GET['height']; ?>">.

then use the url "page.php?width=100%25&height=100%25" to pass in 100%

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about pure JavaScript, the below example should work fine.

```
// Select your button
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// Button event listener for click
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

// Button function
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.cssText = 'width: 600px !important; height: 600px !important;';
}
```

I've tested the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chzz73sx/). Check it out.

---

I think you were focusing within the iFrame too much. You have to focus on things you can work with. In this case, trying to modify the `url` attribute won't do anything because that isn't what controls the `iframe` width and height.

The element controls the appearance of itself. So you must use CSS or attributes provided with the iFrame. In this case I choose to go with CSS via JavaScript.

---

I didn't provide a jQuery or 3rd party solution because the user specified JavaScript and it looked like he or she has not implemented any of it throughout the code.

But to entertain the thought, here is a jQuery solution:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#myFrame').css("cssText", "width: 600px !important; height: 600px !important;");
});
```

A much cleaner approach!

Comment: thanks a lot for your ard work but your code works only to resize iframe but not the link. i know you said "trying to modify the url attribute won't do anything because that isn't what controls the iframe width and height" but dear i need the code to work on resizing link also i mean here `page.php?width=400&height=400` the width and height. because some page on iframe doesn't resize the link automatically. like youube videos i only have to resize iframe no need for its src link.

Answer (score 0):

Handle iframe sizing depending on the content is often complicated, I'd recommend using a 3rd party solution like https://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/ (I'm not related to it, but I've used it several times, no issues at all).

You can give a try and see if that suits your needs.

Hope this helps